# How do I convert images, documents, audio or video using only javascript to other file formats on the front-end?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I want to be able to convert pdf's to png, jpg or heic images for example. Or convert mp4 to mp3. As many different file formats as possible I need to be able to convert to other file formats. How do I do that?

Comment: use ffmpeg compiled to wasm.

Comment: You should search for a library that helps you with that specific convert. There is no way to convert files in default Javascript. I even don't think there is one library that does all conversions.